# Select multiple directories on start using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on Android 11+

Tags: java, android

I want my app to allow the user to select multiple directories on app start using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`  instead of asking him for a single directory and spamming multiple requests for others. Is it possible to make a one time request for multiple paths on app start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` supports selecting only one document tree, not several. There is no `Intent` action to request multiple trees at one time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Google sure got some lacking devs.